# Performing a JOIN in LINQ with a strongly-typed object

Tags: c#, linq

I have two objects that have been generated with an entity data model. The objects look like the following:

```
public class Song
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public double Duration { get; set; }
}

public class AlbumSongLookup
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int SongID { get; set; }
  public int AlbumID { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get the Song objects for an Album using LINQ. I have the Album ID. Currently, I'm trying:

```
int albumID = GetAlbumID();
var results = from lookup in context.AlbumSongLookups
              where lookup.AlbumID=albumID
              select lookup;
```

I understand that I need to do a join. But what I'm not sure about is, how do I get the results to be Song objects with this LINQ query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this query return what you're expecting?

```
var results = from lookup in context.AlbumSongLookups
              join song in context.Songs on lookup.SongID equals song.ID
              where lookup.AlbumID == albumID
              select song;
```

I'm assuming the existence of **context.Songs** here.

Answer (score 0):

does this not work?

```
from lookup in context.AlbumSongLookups
from songs in context.Song
where lookup.SongID == songs.ID && lookup.SongID == albumID
select songs
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "Navigation Property" to your "Song" Entity, this way, you'll be able to directly access the corresponding Songs of a particular album. Entity framework will do the heavy lifting for you.

In your case, it returns a collection of lookups, what you need to do is look for the Song objects corresponding to them. this can be done using:

```
int albumID = GetAlbumID();
var results = from lookup in context.AlbumSongLookups
              where lookup.AlbumID=albumID
              select context.Songs.SingleOrDefault(s=>s.SongID==lookup.SongID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
int albumID = GetAlbumID();
var songIDs = from lookup in contenxt.AlbumSongLookups
              where lookup.AlbumID == albumID
              select lookup.SongID;
var results = from song in context.Songs
              where song.SongID in SongIDs
              select song;
```